# Is it possible to set a cookie in Laravel 5.1 from the routes file?

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have a route defined in my routes file

```
Route::get('/deals-coupons/{merchant_url_text}', function($merchant_url_text) {
return view('mlpdeals', ['merchant_url_text' => $merchant_url_text]);
});
```

I want to set a cookie value when a user goes to this route in Laravel 5.1. I tried the below route but its not working.

```
Route::get('/deals-coupons/{merchant_url_text}', function($merchant_url_text) {
return view('mlpdeals', ['merchant_url_text' => $merchant_url_text])->withCookie('testcookie', 'abcdef');
});
```

I checked the documentation but it shows example of setting cookie from Controller. Is it possible to set cookie like this just from route?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

It's the same function anyway.

```
/**
 * Add a cookie to the response.
 *
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie|mixed  $cookie
 * @return $this
 */
public function withCookie($cookie)
{
    if (is_string($cookie) && function_exists('cookie')) {
        $cookie = call_user_func_array('cookie', func_get_args());
    }

    $this->headers->setCookie($cookie);

    return $this;
}
```

`withCookie` method simply calles the `setCookie` method on the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag` class.